# Creating Java Entity Classes in Netbeans

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I am trying to learn JavaFX so that I can create a desktop application that communicates with a database (currently using SQLite).

So far, Netbeans is able to connect to the SQLite database. I believe the next step is to create entity classes, which represent database tables, so I went ahead and did that in Netbeans: *File > New Project > Java > Java Class Library*. Then in *Projects window > right-click the project > File > New File > Persistence > "Entity Classes from Database"*

Now my projects window looks like this:

[image]

My questions are:

1. What is the next step?
2. How do I use the entity classes in my HelloWorld project?

Thanks!

Comment: Netbeans has a great tutorial in how to access your DB in a EJB environment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html It goes from connecting the IDE to your mySQL database, creating entities from it and making them available to the rest of the framework through facades.
You should look at the "Adding Session Beans" section. I hope I've helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a number of small applications utilizing both JavaFX and JPA.  JPA has been promoted more in the world of webserver applications, but it can certainly work in a JavaFX project too, in which case you'll be using an "application managed entity manager."

So that's your first step: getting an entity manager available to your code.  Given the fact that Netbeans has saved a persistence.xml for your project, you should be able to get your entity manager with a couple steps of code like:

```
// Declare variables as part of an application or controller class
EntityManagerFactory factory = null;
EntityManager entityManager = null;

// Attempt to get a connection somewhere in your code:
// Perhaps startup, but that's not always ideal
// especially if it delays appearance of your application.
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyDataPU");
entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
```

You'll need to confirm the proper argument for createEntityManagerFactory() by matching the PU (Persistence Unit) name in persistence.xml.  At this point in your code, as long as your entityManager is not null, you should now have what you need to retrieve a record, perform a query, or execute a stored procedure.  The most basic operation would be to retrieve one of your Person entities with the find() operation:

```
Person oPersonAdmin = entityManager.find(Person.class, 1);
```

... as an example, which would retrieve the Person with an ID of 1: assuming this is the main user in a simple application.

For a more flexible retrieval of data, you'll want to use a TypedQuery, which is generated by the EntityManager based on a JPQL query string (similar to SQL) and an argument specifying the class for the data returned. See the API for details:

[CreateQuery(String qlString, Class<T> resultClass)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)